# Tastypie and token authorization

Tags: python, django, authentication, token, tastypie

I new in Django. I need to write API for using from mobile devices. I decided to use Tastypie framework for this. Everything is clear here but I can't find a fully described solution for authentication realization for such API. So here is a couple of questions:

1) How to create token authentication with django and tastypie
2) How to get token on client (curl request example is enough here)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tastypie Documentation has very clear explanation on how to implement custom authentication and authorization. Please refer to [Authentication](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#implementing-your-own-authentication-authorization) and [Authorization](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html#implementing-your-own-authorization)

Comment: accessing token (if, for example, token is in url param) is via `bundle.request.GET.get('token')`

Comment: So I need to 1) Implement my own Authentication subclass and 2) create my own token creation/expiration mechanism?

Comment: @earsonheart, yes, basically you might want to create a model named `Token`with expiration date and it's value, and then compare to what `request.GET.get('token')` returns.